# Call of Duty United Offensive Windows Server binaries

Tags: call-of-duty-united-offensive

I wanted to start a United Offensive server on my PC but I just can't find the binaries. Only the Linux ones.

Any idea where can I get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot download it separately**, it's within the game's folder. (So you need to install it on your server)

Here's a [config guide](http://guides.tntblowout.com/coduo/index.html)

Comment: .....Thank you! (And sorry for the late reply, I thought no one will answer.)